# The size modifiers are ignored inside a Surface

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I am new to Compose. I use the following code:

```kotlin
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .height(100.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
    backgroundColor = Color.Gray
)
```

But for some unknown reason `Card` takes up the whole screen and changes its size only if you use required modifiers. `fillMaxWidth(0.2f)` doesn't work either. Help, please.

Only `requiredHeight` and `requiredWidth` work. The rest of the menus are fine

Comment: What's the sourounding code?

Comment: What is the parent container?

Comment: I just have it in Compose. That is, it is not in any parent element. What does sourounding code mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are using as parent container of the `Card` a `Surface`. It is a `Box` with **`propagateMinConstraints = true`** parameter which forces first descendant to have same minimum constraints or dimensions.

In the doc:

> If `propagateMinConstraints` is set to true, the min size set on the Box **will also be applied to the content**, whereas otherwise the min size will only apply to the `Box.`

Use a Column to wrap the `Card`.

```
 Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
 ){
    Column(){

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(100.dp)
                .height(100.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.Gray
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's all working.